# How to mirror exact same symbology from ArcGIS Pro to ArcGIS Online?

Tags: arcgis-pro, symbology, arcgis-online

I have a polygon layer with 7 categories that are styled differently. All the styles are relatively unique hatches, similar to what you would often find in CAD drawings.

I tried to share the layer from Pro to AGOL as a simple feature service, vector tile and tile layer, but AGOL cannot replicate the symbology. In fact, it's not even close. I kinda assumed tile layer would solve the issue but it didn't.

Any idea what I could do to replicate the Pro styles in AGOL? I don't really need layers to be clickable in AGOL, just need the whole thing to "look nice".

Comment: Are you willing to share your bespoke symbology as a style file for people to test?

Comment: @Hornbydd Yep, should be available on this link https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/11_JFKIEs1vxpiHcmf9MRi4JLv-urRn_J?usp=sharing

Comment: Based on a discussion from this post below, I would assume custom styles in AGOL are not supported yet for lines and polygons, only for points. Would you know if that's still true as of 2022?


@Hornbydd https://www.esri.com/arcgis-blog/products/arcgis-online/mapping/use-published-2d-symbols-in-arcgis-online/#:~:text=With%20the%20release%20of%20ArcGIS,symbols%20for%20styling%20point%20features.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the time of the writing, hatches for polygons in ArcGIS Online were not yet a supported feature. I found a great workaround with creating patterns in Illustrator or similar software, exporting them as image and applying image fill to the layers.

The complete tutorial that solved my issue:

https://www.esri.com/arcgis-blog/products/arcgis-pro/mapping/hatched-fills-and-how-to-sneak-them-into-arcgis-online/

Or if you are willing to play a bit with the backend which will bring the actual hatching through and not just the image fill, you can follow the steps in the discussion by DeVoe_William

https://community.esri.com/t5/arcgis-online-questions/can-i-use-my-own-polygon-pattern-for-symbology-in/td-p/146482